# libgit2 in long running process: How to close open handles?

Tags: windows, libgit2

libgit2 caches "open" pack-file handles and, thus, locks those files (at least on Windows).

If libgit2 is used in a long running process, this is not desirable if you don't want to open a repository again and again.

Is there a way to clear the cache and close all open handles w/o freeing the repository and re-open it again and again?